# UICollectionView behavior is incorrect as Subview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I added `UICollectionView` as subview in another controller. I set frame for it and `UICollectionView` flow is horizontal. I need to show only 1 row of items and scrolling by horizontal. But I get several rows by vertical. I tried some several different methods but it doesn't help me. I searched information about it but these methods also don't help me. How can I fix it?

My code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addUIElements()
}

// MARK: - UI functions

private func addUIElements() {
    view.addSubview(headerView)

    let lifelineController = StoryboardManager.lifeLineStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LifeLineCollectionViewController") as! LifeLineCollectionViewController
    addChildViewController(lifelineController)
    lifelineController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: headerView.frame.height, width: headerView.frame.width, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(lifelineController.view)
    lifelineController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Layout code

```
    extension LifeLineCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let value = 50
        return CGSize(width: value, height: value)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }

//    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
//        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 376)
//    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let top: CGFloat = 48
        let cornerValue: CGFloat = 8
        let bottom: CGFloat = 40
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: cornerValue, bottom: bottom, right: cornerValue)
    }
}
```

My result is 
[image]

I printed in UICollectionView in viewDidAppear its frame and I get a completely different result 508 height but I set 136 to height.

Comment: What's the layout, the frame height, the item height and the insets values?

Comment: @Wain please loot at Layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with help of SnapKit

```
    private func addUIElements() {
    view.addSubview(headerView)

    let lifelineController = StoryboardManager.lifeLineStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LifeLineCollectionViewController") as! LifeLineCollectionViewController
    addChildViewController(lifelineController)
    view.addSubview(lifelineController.view)
    lifelineController.view.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(headerView.frame.width)
        make.height.equalTo(136)
        make.centerX.equalTo(view.snp_centerX)
        make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp_bottom)
    }
    lifelineController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```